# Virtualbox Host Key - How to Change

Tags: virtualbox

virtual box host key correction.  the menus above on the software show as follows:  Machine / View / Devices / Help ... other information states "file then preferences" but that's for a windows host.  i have ubuntu has the host os.  i have searched the Virtualbox manual and no find for solution.

Answer (score 23):

#### Change Virtual Box Host Key

1. From the Top Menu choose *File > Preferences...*
2. Select *Input > Virtual Machine* tab
3. Select *Shortcut* in the *Host Key Combination* line:

   [image]
4. Press new key shortcut
5. click *Ok* to save changes