# Remap Menu to Control key (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox on Microsoft Surface Pro (2017). Unfortunately that keyboard doesn't have a right control key, but just a menu key on the right. That's why I want to swap the menu key for right control key.

I tried to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin` by changing this

```
// Menu is mapped to the Menu key.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "menu" {
    key  { [ Menu ] };
};
```

to that

```
// Menu is mapped to the Menu key.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "menu" {
    key  { [ Control_R ] };
};
```

and then logged in again, but unfortunately it does not work.

How is this done correctly?

Comment: Command in your case is probably: `setxkbmap -option ctrl:menu_rctrl` (the linked question provides guidance on how you can make the change persistent).

Comment: If it was for changing the Virtual Box HOST-key see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854116/virtualbox-host-key-how-to-change